# Combine tab layout and tab swipe

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I've implemented tab layout it works, but when I add tab swipe. it freeze I can't use the other tabs in the tab layout. Any suggestions.

Here's my code for the tab layout

```
public class TabLayoutAdmin extends TabActivity {

private TabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tablayoutadmin);
    Resources res= getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    Intent confirmedList = new Intent().setClass(this, Reservations.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecConfirmedList= tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Android")
            .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.stadimumspage))
            .setContent(confirmedList);


    Intent stadiumsPage = new Intent().setClass(this, StadiumsPage.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecStadiumsPage = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Apple")
            .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newreservation))
            .setContent(stadiumsPage);

    Intent newReservation = new Intent().setClass(this, NewReservation.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecNewReservation= tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Windows")
            .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.confirmedlist))
            .setContent(newReservation);


    Intent blockTeam = new Intent().setClass(this, Block_Team.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecBlockTeam = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Berry")
            .setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.blockteam))
            .setContent(blockTeam);

    // add all tabs
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecConfirmedList);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecStadiumsPage);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecNewReservation);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpecBlockTeam);

    //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

As for tab swipe I used this code
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Thanks

Comment: TabActivity was deprecated in API level 13.  You should be using a TabLayout with Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TabLayout to hold the fragments and ViewPager for swipe, here's how to do it step by step: [tablayout with viewpager](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/)